# Unable to disable edit access for a field in visual force page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I'm trying to remove edit access for a field for the users with specific conditions. I've tried with input text & disabled tag working perfectly fine but I've faced some issues with some users due to input text tag.

So, i want to disable the edit access through the script but it is not working. Could you suggest the best way to remove edit access?

Script Code:

```
<script>
    function changeVar(e){
        if(isEditAllowed){
            document.querySelectorAll(input[id$=inputToDisable]")[0].disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Vf Tag:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Total units ordered">
            <apex:inputField value="{!pro.Total_units_ordered__c}" style="width:50px" id="inputToDisable" />
          </apex:column>
```

Apex Class:

```
If(Userinfo.getProfileId() !=full &&(UserInfo.getUserId() == caseslist.ownerid || Userinfo.getProfileId() ==systemadmin ))
     {
         isEditAllowed = true;
         //isEditNotAllowed = false;
     }
     else 
     {
         isEditAllowed = false;
         //isEditNotAllowed = true;
     }
```

Please suggest the best practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the rendered attribute to show either an input or output field:

```
<apex:inputField rendered="{!isEditAllowed}" value="{!pro.Total_units_ordered__c}" style="width:50px" id="inputToDisable" />
<apex:outputField rendered="{!NOT(isEditAllowed)}" value="{!pro.Total_units_ordered__c}" style="width:50px" id="inputToDisable" />
```

This will work for all types of fields, while trying to use JavaScript may not work on all field types. Also, I find the output easier to read, since you don't get a disabled gray background on the input.

Comment: It works like charm. My bad i didn't think through this way